# Proof of lemma on parameters in natural deduction

Tags: logic, proof-theory, natural-deduction

I could not understand the proof of the Lemma on parameters on page 29 of this book [(Natural Deduction)](https://books.google.it/books?id=sJj3DQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Dag Prawitz. Why if all proper parameters in a derivation $\pi$ are pure, $\pi$ will satisfy 3 clauses as stated in the Lemma?
(On page 28 and 29, a pure parameter $a$ has the properties of (a) being the only proper parameter of an application $\alpha$ of $\forall I$ or $\exists E$, and  (b) all formula occurrences $B$s where $a$ occurs in $B$s are linked by $a$ to the premiss or discharged premiss of $\alpha$.)

Specifically,

1. Why in a deduction $\pi$ whose proper parameters are pure, every proper parameter used by a quantifier rule $\alpha$ ($\forall I$ or $\exists E$) is a proper parameter of **exactly one** quantifier rule in the derivation? (Or put it differently, how the second property of a pure parameter $a$ is violated if it occurs twice in 2 different $\alpha$ ?)
2. Why if a pure parameter $a$ is used by an application $\alpha$ of $\forall I$ or $\exists E$, then it occurs only in the part of the derivation above $\alpha$?

   I tried to cook up a counter example as follows. Let $\pi$ be the derivation $\forall xPx$ $\rightarrow$ $Pa$ $\rightarrow$ $\forall xPx$ $\rightarrow$ $Pa\supset\forall xPx$. The bottom formula ($Pa\supset\forall xPx$) occurs below $Pa$ and is linked to $Pa$ by $a$ (by clause 4 of the definition of a connection between 2 formulas in page 28). So $a$ is still a pure parameter in $\pi$, but it occurs below the consequence of $\forall I$.

Comment: Maybe some more details may help... Are you considering the Lemma of page 29 regarding the rules for quantifiers of [Natural Deduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=sJj3DQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)?

Comment: The idea is: in order to avoid problems with the restrictions of the rules for quantifiers, we can always rename parameters in order that they are new in the proof.

Comment: Yes I am working on that Lemma. Thanks for the hint. I will think more about your suggestion and improve my question.

Comment: 2nd bullett: not very clear... Are you discharging $Pa$? It is not an assumption. If so, apply Prawitz's "renaming parameter" procedure: $\forall x Px \vdash Pb \vdash \forall x Px \vdash Pa \supset \forall xPx$. Here I0ve discharged an assumption that was not explicit (I can do it) and the result is that now $a$ is new for the further apllication of $\forall \text I$.

Comment: In the last step of the new derivation, it seems to me that you can't get the bottom formula with ⊃I. The antecedent is Pb and not Pa. So perhaps the new derivation is not valid?

Comment: What I mean is: rewrite it as $\forall xPx,Pa \vdash \forall x Px [\text { by } (\forall \text I)] \vdash Pa \supset \forall x Px [\text { by } (\supset \text I)]$. The result is the same and the *parameter* $a$ does not occur below the application $\alpha$ of $(\forall \text I)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of the Lemma [page 29 of Dag Prawitz's [Natural Deduction (1965)](https://books.google.it/books?id=sJj3DQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)] regards the management of *parameters* in the quantifier rules.

A couple of rules has restrictions on the parameter used: the simple example is the restriction of the $(∀ \text I)$ rule where the parameter $a$ must not occur free in some open assumption [reason: we cannot "generalize" on the assumption $x=0$ to derive the incorrect $∀x(x=0)$].

The simplest way to fulfill the restrictions is that:

- every parameter used by a quantifier rule is used only once in the derivation, and
- if a parameter $a$ is used by an application $\alpha$ of a rule, then it occurs only in the part of the derivation above $\alpha$.

The Lemma describe a procedure that applied to a derivation $\Pi$ transforms it in a new derivation where all parameters are *pure*: in a nutshell, start from the uppermost application $\alpha$ of a quantifier rule with restriction and if the parameter $a$ of $\alpha$ is not *pure*, replace it with a fresh parameter $b$ that is not used in $\Pi$.

---

The gist of the "purification" procedure is that, in order to avoid potential clash between variables, we can always transform a derivation $\Pi$ in an "equivalent" one (same assumptions, same conclusion) $\Pi'$ such that:

- no variable occurs in $\Pi'$ both free and bound: and this is achieved in Prawitz's system using *parameter* (free) and *variables* (bound), and
- all parameters are distinct and different from the remaining parameters occurring in $\Pi'$: they are used only once.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I have improved my question so that it is more precise. Please have a look. Thanks again!